# How to run Cypress component tests in CI

Tags: cypress

I've just started using Component tests (Svelte) and they run in the Cypress GUI without problem. Now I want to put them in CI, but when I use run mode only the e2e tests are running.

What I've tried:

```js
yarn cypress run

npx cypress run
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the `--component` flag on the command line to run component tests:

```js
yarn cypress run --component
```